.NET Aspire: How to use ServiceProviderOptions when using DistributedApplication?
I would like to enforce proper singleton and scoped usage in a .NET project using Aspire.
In a previous project, I did something like:
new HostBuilder()
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new DefaultServiceProviderFactory(new ServiceProviderOptions
    {
        ValidateOnBuild = true,
        ValidateScopes = true,
    }))

I can't figure out how to enforce similar guards with DistributedApplication from Aspire. Is it possible yet?

I suppose I could do builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider(new ServiceProviderOptions() { ValidateOnBuild = true, ValidateScopes = true,}); but that seems wasteful as we're not already calling BuildServiceProvider and I don't see a way to use re-use one we build 'manually'.
